# cl : Command line error D8021 : invalid numeric argument '/Wno-cpp'

Tags: python, windows, caffe

I met a problem in windows 10 CMD, when I try to compile a .py file for coco dataset, then the problem occurred. The information can be see below:

```
    running build_ext
    building 'pycocotools._mask' extension
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IE:\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -I../common -IE:\Anaconda2\include -IE:\Anaconda2\PC /Tcpycocotools/_mask.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\pycocotools/_mask.obj -Wno-cpp -Wno-unused-function -std=c99
    cl : Command line error D8021 : invalid numeric argument '/Wno-cpp'
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

I have searched for some information to solve it,but I only do it in my cmd line,not with Visual studio,perhaps the system really use it,but I also set it by " SET VS90COMNTOOLS=%VS140COMNTOOLS%",this is my version,but it doesn't work.
Thank you for advice!

Comment: sounds like gcc options slipped in the MSVC command line...

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre  Because this job was did in windows system, it seems more likely to run in ubuntu? Right? Here is the website: https://github.com/weiliu89/caffe/tree/ssd/data/coco

Comment: I would search through the config files to remove those `-Wno-xxx` options from the scripts. There may exist some more config options, but those are generally hell, yes, designed for linux and ported to windows, with minimum effort.

Answer (score 1):

Please, refer to the following updated repo that solves the `cl : Command line error D8021 : invalid numeric argument '/Wno-cpp'`: https://github.com/philferriere/cocoapi

Clone the repo and navigate to the PythonAPI folder and run `python setup.py install`. Make sure that you have downloaded the latest build-in tools for Visual Studio https://www.scivision.dev/python-windows-visual-c-14-required/